# How can I list all my questions and answers across all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, questions

I have an account on several Stack Exchange sites.

How can I list all my questions and answers across all Stack Exchange sites ?

Is there any dashboard that would show me all my questions (and answers) across Stack Overflow, Server Fault, etc ? I don't like the idea of having to log on every site just to check for answers.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148268/directly-support-cross-site-queries-in-the-data-explorer, which would make this easily possible using the Data Explorer.

Comment: I posted an answer here of my free open-source code that lets you download as JSON files all of your content from across all Stack Exchange sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315243/189207

Answer (score 6):

You can check your top answers and questions on [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/23281). It's not exactly what you're asking for, but it's the closest I can think of to it.

If all you want to know is when your get replies, that's what the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ is for! If all your accounts are connected, you should see the notification at the top left of the screen whenever someone replies to your questions:

[image]

When you click on it, you'll be able to see all the answers to questions you asked across the StackExchange Network (among other things):

[image]

Comment: Ok, but this is a notification area, not really somewhere to check for all the questions you've ever asked across all the sites.

Comment: @Benoît: I'm not sure I understand the difference. It tells you whenever there's a new answer to one of your questions or a new comment on your question. What functionality is missing?

Comment: In my profile (when i click on my name), there is a board where i can see all the questions i've asked. There are the stats, activity, etc tabs. I'd like to get the same kind of information across all the StackExchange sites.

Comment: Sorry, notifier is nice, but not what we need. How can we learn from our past, if we don't have access to it?

Comment: perhaps there is an app that exists on stack apps? they have a robust api. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97511/what-is-the-easiest-way-for-me-to-download-all-my-questionsanswers-across-all

Answer (score 5):

It's just a partial solution, but your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/23281) displays all your questions with a score >4. You'll find the link at the top right corner of any of your site profiles as well.

Answer (score 1):

To Abe, it sounds like you're looking for [the StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

It's currently limited to querying one site at a time, and so doesn't quite give you the global reach you'd like, but switching between sites while keeping the same query is fairly painless.

See e.g. [My Questions and Answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81177/my-questions-and-answers).  (Log in to have UserId filled in automatically when switching between sites).