# Export My Stack Overflow Data

Tags: support, export

Is there a first party (or third party?) way to export **just my** data out of Stack Overflow?

I realize there's a massive Creative Commons data dump.  I'm interested in knowing if there's a quick and easy way for me to get my posts dumped out in some plain text file format for easy  personal archiving.

Comment: Bur doesn't the data dump allow you quite simply to query only your data? And it has loads of export options...

Comment: What do you define as 'data'? Questions and answers obviously, but comments, votes, user profile info, too? Some of your data is simply *not available* because private user data is not exposed through the public channels that are offered.

Comment: That sounds like it could become awfully 'expensive' in terms of resource consumption on the DB servers.

Comment: Do you mean like Facebook allow you to do? For the un-initated, Facebook allow you to do an offline export of your profile, which gives you your profile, history, photos, and virtually everything attached to your profile.

Comment: If anyone is still interested in this, I could put together a query if you give some specifics of what should be included...

Comment: @ashleedawg I think it would be awesome to have a PHP script that accepts an array of StackExchange sites as arguments and then outputs all of my questions, answers, and comments (including the body of the text, the tags, the IDs, the URLs, etc) into JSON.

Comment: I just found this Data Explorer tool that is pretty fast and helpful. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/848322/1047444/posts-where-owneruserid

Comment: I finally coded the PHP project I was hoping for.  Answer below: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315243/189207

Answer (score 14):

How about [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/96830/) on data explorer?

```
select * from posts where owneruserid=4668;​
```

Comment: It seems only my own post can be exported. How to export the replies as well?

Answer (score 8):

### Free, open-source Laravel (PHP) Stack Exchange data exporter

I finally coded it and released it as a Composer package for Laravel on [Github](https://github.com/ryancwalsh/StackExchangeBackupLaravelPHP).

**This is the first time I've ever created an open-source package, so I'd LOVE to hear if this ends up being useful for anyone.**

It exports JSON files of your activity across all of your Stack Exchange sites, such as:

[image]

Comment: This looks really good, is there a demo so I can see the end result webpage? I assume it's got a frontend

Comment: @Jonathan It's been really helpful for me personally not just for knowing that all my StackExchange "work" is backed up but more for being able to quickly search the folder of JSON files for text phrases to find activity of mine where I can only vaguely remember what I'd said. There is no web front end. You just run `php artisan exportStackExchange` in the console.

Comment: would you be open to collaborating to make a front end? I would be interested

Answer (score 1):

No, currently there's only the data dump.

However, there might be a Stack App that will grab all your activity from SO and put it in a printer friendly format.

Comment: For that, you'd have to define 'my activity' too: all my comments out of context isn't much use :)

Comment: Even if they are most excellent comments, (I hasten to add)