# Printing out all my posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked this question on EL&U Meta and it was suggested I post it here.

Does anybody know if there is a way that I could print out all of my answers and or questions on E&U or another SE site without going to each individual page and printing it off?

Also, do we want there to be a print button on pages? I quite often want to print out other peoples answers. It's a bind having to select them etc.

Comment: For a single question there's already a feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/printing-out-stack-overflow-exchange-qas-including-comments

Comment: @rene I don't want hundreds of HTML pages I want hundreds of paper pages!

Comment: Probably [stackprinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) can be tweaked, but still - don't think we need a separate feature request for that.

Comment: See [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) - you can leave a comment to the author, he appears to be active.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What I want it to print off all my answers with one command. I don't understand how the linked to question would address this? Putting all my question ID's into stack printer is even *more* time consuming that going to every sing page and copying and pasting the content onto word. It means having to go and retrieve all the question numbers.

Comment: @Araucaria well, each browser I know is capable of printing so you can ruin as many trees as you want.

Comment: @rene I've checked out your answer on the linked-to question more thoroughly, and wit will indeed work. Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer here of my free open-source code that lets you download as JSON files all of your content from across all Stack Exchange sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315243/189207