# Download my voting data

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, export, community-data

For my own data analysis reasons, it would be useful to have a dump of votes that I've cast on a particular site.  I would normally use the SEDE and/or the data dumps, but voting data has been sanitized from these datasets.

I'd love to see a link on the "private view" of my profile page to download a CSV of my voting information.  Example (featuring freehand circle!):

[image: possible user interface example]

Clicking on this link could then provide a CSV/XML/whatnot file (or a zip of multiple such files) containing the data within this "votes" tab.  This doesn't need a lot of data (for example, the schema could be something like `vote_datetime, post_id, vote_type`), but just enough to piece together other relevant information with the publicly available data dumps.  For my particular application, including this data about votes on deleted posts would be most helpful.

Otherwise, I'm currently left with the (much inferior) solution of writing a scraper for this particular page to get the relevant data. ;)

Related (old) question about non-voting data: [Export My Stack Overflow Data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77331/201314)

Comment: I want this too! For massive data analysis / quantified self. Could create a resume from it.