# Top voted questions not voted by me

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

How can I get top voted questions by tag, that are not voted by me (down/up).

Can you help me with a SEDE query, or easier solution?

**Edit**

If above query is not possible, Can it be possible

- To get top voted questions by tag, that are not answered by me.
- To get top viewed questions by tag, that are not answered by me.

Comment: SEDE can't see how you voted. You can get the top voted questions questions per tag though.

Comment: Can this query build for not viewed by me?

Comment: @RobertLongson As you said SEDE can't see my votes. So can I have query for top voted question that were not viewed by me.

Comment: SEDE doesn't retain information on who viewed things, just a view count, so no you can't do that either.

Comment: Not sure why is this helpful.

Comment: @user202729 Because there are many questions, which I seen, those answers are deprecated or better solution exist now. So I want to see questions, do they have the updated answer. And edit if it is old solution.

Comment: If it was possible to export in some way your voting data, you could combine this with output from SEDE locally. So perhaps you might support this feature request: [Download my voting data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293435).

Comment: I am pretty sure that it can be improved in various ways, but I have at least tried to create some query concerning your edited question - you can see it [in the SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7186633#7186633).

Answer (score 1):

I've created this [SEDE Pivot Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1692471?owner=6891563&tagame=android) to get a ranked list showing the questions with either the ranking based on score or on view count.

The query starts with two Common Table Expressions to get the answers for the OP and then find the questions that are not answered by the OP. In that query we also calculate the rank ([row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) basically because I can't deal with non-unique ranking numbers which [Rank](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [Dense_Rank](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) won't guarantee).

After that we union the questions query twice, once for score rank and once for views rank. Once the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) did its magic we custom build a clickable title link  with the [auto-linking feature](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns).

Here is the whole query:

```
;with answers_by_op as (
select distinct parentid 
from posts 
where posttypeid = 2 -- Answers
and owneruserid = ##owner:int?6891563##
),
questions as (
select p.id
     , p.score
     , p.viewcount
     , row_number() over (order by p.score desc) [score rank]
     , row_number() over (order by p.viewcount desc) [views rank]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
left outer join answers_by_op a on a.parentid = p.id
where t.tagname = ##tagame:string?android##
and p.closeddate is null
and a.parentid is null
)

select top 1000 
       rank
     , concat('site://q/', main.score, '|', s.title ) [Ranked by Score]
     , concat('site://q/', main.views, '|', v.title ) [Ranked by Views]
from 
(
  select [rank]
       , [1] as [score]
       , [2] as [views]
  from (
  select [score rank] [rank]
       , id
       , 1 [type]
  from questions
  union all 
  select [views rank] [rank]
       , id
       , 2 [type]
  from questions
  ) as data
  pivot  (
        max(id)
       for [type] in ([1],[2])
  ) as pvt
) as  main
inner join posts s on s.id = main.score
inner join posts v on v.id = main.views
order by 1
```

When run today this is the result:

[image: list of ranked posts with links to score and viewed ranks]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the very useful [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the awesome [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).