# Is there a way of downloading one's questions from the Mathematics Stack Exchange site into Lyx/Latex or PDF form or conversely

Tags: feature-request, support, mathjax

Is there a way of downloading ones's questions on, Math Stack Exchange site into Lyx/LaTeX or PDF form or conversely. I.e. is there a feature that allows me to download my own questions from Math Stack Exchange as PDF files, and, or which translates it into Lyx/LaTeX code directly?

Moreover is there a feature that allows me to upload documents from Lyx (in Lyx code) directly as questions into Math Stack Exchange? Rather than having to re-correct the formatting. If so that would be beneficial.

As I find using Lyx, quicker, and less likely for my questions to be unclear.

My questions which are often convoluted otherwise, may not be. It would also allow to be keep track of my drafts, and repeats, duplicates, deleted questions, etc...

Comment: Short answer is no. Your browser can print arbitrary websites as PDF documents though. SE included.

Comment: Thanks for thisl Howevever, could you pleaes clarify what you mean parting  arbitrary websites as pdfs (as in do you mean there is an option in many browsers such as mozilla or chrome that allows you to convert webpages into pdf?)

Comment: Sorry, "part" was an autocorrect error for "print". Yes. If you say "print page" in any browser, one of the options should be "to PDF". That will save the webpage as a PDF document locally on your computer. If you're not sure how to do this, you can Google it.

Comment: Maybe any of the options offered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269804/158100) can also help.

Comment: This appears to be specific to Math.SE, better post this on their own meta.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Kinda sounds as though it would apply to most sites with MathJax.

Comment: Seconding Nathan and leaving this open. Just because only one site is mentioned doesn't mean it only affects one site @Sha Wiz.

Comment: I posted an answer here of my free open-source code that lets you download as JSON files all of your content from across all Stack Exchange sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315243/189207