# Why was my answer deleted, and why wasn't I notified?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderation

I provided an answer for this question:

[Override inherited method as private in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266139/override-inherited-method-as-private-in-objective-c/20403449#20403449)

My answer refers to another related Q, instead of copy-and-pasting the answer.  This made more sense than marking it as a dupe in this case b/c the way that the question was stated leaves room for other types of solutions than the one that is linked.

It's unclear to me why this answer would be deleted, based upon the expectations of the forum.  And though it probably doesn't matter, the answer had already received an up-vote at the time it was deleted, so it seems that someone had found value in it.

I'm also surprised that I did not receive notification that it was deleted.  I only happened to notice because I've only recently signed up to be a contributor and my reputation is small enough to notice the fluctuation from an answer disappearing.

Comment: Related: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) and [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)

Comment: That should have been a comment, as it's not really an answer.

Comment: @Servy the link points to a Stack Overflow question, though, not an external resource.

Comment: @Pëkka But it's not a duplicate (at least, the author felt it wasn't) so you can apply the same logic to such a link.  All of those reasons apply to such a link.

Comment: @Charles Maybe, but the OP didn't have enough rep to comment. At the very least, the answer should have been converted into one

Comment: @Pëkka Which of course doesn't mean he should be posting comments as answers.

Comment: @Servy that may be obvious to you and me, but not to a new user who actually has constructive, helpful information to bring to the table. That's what the "convert to comment" moderator tool is there for, right? (I can see how SO sometimes feels like a sadistic bureaucracy to outsiders after a contact with Meta. "You need Form 17 B to complete form 5 B". - "But it says here that to get 17 B, I need to fill in 5 B first" - "Yes but you need Form 17 B to get 5 B")

Comment: Also related: [When a user has one of his questions or answers deleted, why don't you notify him?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209694)

Comment: Thanks for your responses, guys.  I wasn't using answer to circumvent the fact that I couldn't comment, fwiw.  I genuinely felt that the 90% case for the Q was answered in the other question.  But due to the 10%, I didn't think suggesting dupe was the right answer either.  In this case, what would be my recommended course of action for properly contributing to the question?

Comment: Re: no notify - thanks Josh.  In my ONE encounter, a system for notifying and a method for directly responding to the mod that deleted me would have probably been appropriate. But I get the intent. And this exchange was also useful and informative.

Comment: @J.Paulding I think that's the problem — there's *no* defined way that you could contribute properly to the question, as the proper way to do it is to comment, which you don't have enough rep for :)  It's an edge case alright

Comment: @anotherdave That's not true; he could have expanded on the link to the point where it could make a good answer, he simply didn't do so.  Had he included enough information in the actual text to answer the question, having felt that it wasn't actually a duplicate, it could have made a good answer.

Comment: @Servy I referred directly to the section of the question that addressed similar subject matter to his question, stopping short of copy and pasting the relevant information. Can you give me an example of the sort of additional context that would have helped, in this case?

Comment: @Servy That's true alright, fair point!

Comment: @J.Paulding [Yes I can.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210998/why-was-my-answer-deleted-and-why-wasnt-i-notified?noredirect=1#comment677466_210998)  `"stopping short of copy and pasting the relevant information"` Why are you stopping short of that?  Copy-pasting in the relevant information, obviously citing as appropriate, and including some additional information to tailor it to the question at hand is exactly what you *should* be doing when posting such an answer.  You could paraphrase/summarize instead of actually quoting (while still citing as appropriate) if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand now. Do you think it would be productive for me to answer the question again, taking this feedback into account? Or perhaps the converted comment is good enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was expressed in the comments above, usually when we have an answer that only really points to answers on another question, we tend to convert those into comments. This makes sure the connection is made between the two questions, and preserves any additional color you brought to that connection.

Unfortunately, many answers left like this get flagged with the generic "not an answer" flag, where the easiest response from the moderator tools is to delete. I can see how this was deleted without conversion to a comment, but I've gone ahead and performed the conversion here. I think it was useful to preserve what you said.

Additionally, if the answers at another question are ideal for the one you're commenting on, it's possible that this question is a duplicate of the other one. I'm not entirely convinced that's the case here, because while they tread the same area, this question comes at it from a slightly different angle. If they are true duplicates, flag it and we can point one at the other. That will preserve canonical answers in one place for people searching in the future (this is also why we prefer links pointing to other questions to be in comments, so they don't distract from the original answers).