# What is the highest amount of reputation lost in a single day?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I know what I am asking is a bit weird question, but while surfing around I found the highest reputation gain in a single day. I thought: why not try the highest amount of reputation lost in a single day. **Who lost the most reputation in a single day?**

Comment: That must be caused by reversals or user removed events. Those are not public queryable.

Comment: here is a user removed event that caused some uproar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328642/massive-user-removal-in-one-night

Comment: @rene If I know of a user who lost 19k in one go, but due to voting reversal, is it inappropriate to link to them? The info is public (it's on their rep tab), but I wouldn't seem to be name-calling.

Comment: @Jenayah it is always tricky. If it is not reasonable obtainable with a SEDE query or via the Stack API I consider it as something that is best left to be discovered by everyone on their own. I don't fancy a wiki answer here where we keep a reputation lost league. But that is just my opinion. Do query in the tavern if you want more point of views on the issue. The info being public anyway is a viable stance as well.

Comment: I lost 375 rep on May 25 at [TGO](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/4079/james-jenkins?tab=reputation) Not sure if that is a record.

Comment: Other option is bounties offered, perhaps sede could do some magic on that.

Comment: Anyway, just listing possible events for losing a high amount of reps: spam/rude penalty (100 for each post), bounty (500, maximum 3 active bounties), self-deletion of a user, voting ring nuked.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. putting up bounties is not a loss of rep, it is a spending/trading of rep.  An exchange that the bounty poster believed equitable.

Comment: I’ve cleaned up sock networks, voting rings and plagiarism where the affected account would loose 1000s or points. Not that often but it does happen. No way to query for this, and the general advice is not to go looking because those affected accounts may well have redeemed themselves since.

Comment: (What tragic is that while *1000s* sounds like a lot, it is usually a pittance compared to how much you could earn if you simply write good answers in the time that was used to try and gain that rep illegitimately).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On September 25, 2015, a [user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9003/namaste?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=40) on Mathematics.SE lost **33,934** reputation in a single day as a result of three events:

- 33062 rep lost from a removed user
- 660 rep lost from a different removed user
- 2 rep lost for a downvoted answer

Comment: @Benjamin I have intentionally avoided speculating on whether the 2015 loss is related to the user's present woes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you count suspensions, where a user's reputation drops to 1 for the duration of the suspension period. I know of users with more than 90k reputation who were (quite recently) suspended.

If not, @rene mentions a case which affected almost the entire Stack Exchange network since the deleted user cast a lot of votes on a lot of sites. If you [browse questions posted on child metas around that time](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1085029/meta-posts?fromDate=2019-05-25&tillDate=2019-05-28&query=reputation), you'll see a lot of screenshots by people losing reputation.

But I'm not sure if that event led a user to lose more than 1,000 reputation *on a single site*; [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10927/116151) is a case where somebody on English Language & Usage lost 2,134 reputation because of a user deletion.

Comment: Wow looks like it was Network-wide, too. Some of those screenshots are crazy to see ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGGJ6.png)).