# Rightmost icons are chopped in the achievements dialog

Tags: bug, user-interface, achievements-dialog

Rightmost icons are chopped in the "achievements" dialog:

[image]

[image]

Note that, as [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob) pointed out, it depends on which site you are on: some sites wrap and some overflow. Wrap is better, regardless of how many lines it ends up taking.

[image]

Sometime ago, it [used to work fine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281124/178179):

[image]

---

If you wonder about the downvotes:

- [Massive user removal in one night?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328642/178179)
- [Change the criteria for vote retention upon account removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328646/178179)
- [Always preserve votes from users who are voluntarily removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328673/178179)
- [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125740/178179)
- [How can I prevent my questions from being removed by roomba after a user was removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281124/178179)