# Why the OP does not get link to the deleted post in the reputation tab?

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, reputation-history

The following is from the FAQ item [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139614#139615) ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/139615/12)) in the part related to removed posts: "When a post gets deleted, the question's title will be shown in plain text unless you are able to view the deleted post (10K users or the question owner)."

If I understand it correctly, reputation changes related to deletions of posts are shown in the reputation history just with the title of the question as plain text rather than link - the exception should be 10k+ users and the author of the post.

When I tried this on a site where I have 10k+ reputation, I was indeed shown also the link [to the deleted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177870/multiple-choice-question-for-a-bivariate-function-continuity-invertibility-and/177912#177912).

[image: screenshot from the reputation tab]

However, when I checked [my post which was deleted](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9315/what-should-i-think-about-spammy-invitations-for-publishing-papers-or-even-bo) on a site where I do not have privilege to see deleted questions, I only get regular text (no link) when viewing the reputation tab.

[image: screenshot from the reputation tab]

Is it supposed to work this way? (Since this contradicts the linked [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post, I have tagged this as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). If this is the way it is supposed to work, the linked post probably should be updated to reflect this.)

Comment: I agree, this is very annoying. I've lost over 100 questions thanks to this. Related: [When a user has one of his question or answer deleted, why don't you notify him about the deletion, and send the removed content by email?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209694/178179); [Dump of my own Stack Exchange content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269951/178179).