# Quora users (bots?) are copying a significant amount of Stack Exchange questions to Quora, without proper attribution

Tags: discussion, copyright-infringement, quora

Quora users (bots?) are copying a significant amount of Stack Exchange questions to Quora, without proper attribution. It seems quite systematic.

Examples from https://money.stackexchange.com:

- [Are there any issues with sending money outside of the US?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/119278/5656) https://qr.ae/TV2juJ
- [Is Saikyo Sakura Assets Holding a legit company?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/119275/5656): https://qr.ae/TV2jNx

Examples from https://travel.stackexchange.com:

- [What are the post-DST timezones in the EU/EEA member states?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/151846/1810): https://qr.ae/TV2Lnt
- [Are there any airlines which offer two complimentary checked bags to all passengers on transatlantic flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/151832/1810): https://qr.ae/TV2LPt

I'm guessing that some other Stack Exchange websites are affected.

I wonder whether Quora help organize this content theft because when looking at the profiles of the Quora "users" that copy all questions, such as https://www.quora.com/profile/Dex-Jackson/questions (he's the one copying https://money.stackexchange.com's questions) and https://www.quora.com/profile/Steve-Tang-6/questions (he's the one copying https://travel.stackexchange.com's questions), we don't see the questions in the user profiles, which shouldn't be happening and therefore seems to be some kind of cover up only Quora could technically do, as far as I know.

Anyway, how can we make this systematic content license infringement stop?

---

Updates:

- 2020-01-26: I reported Quora users https://www.quora.com/profile/Dex-Jackson and https://www.quora.com/profile/Steve-Tang-6 to Quora on 2020-01-20: Quora has taken no action yet and hasn't communicated with me. I have noticed that some questions posted on Stack Exchange get copied to Quora in less than one minute, which leads me to think that this copyright infringement process from Quora is automated. For example, [Is the first day of the offering period always the same as the “grant date” in the context of employee stock purchase plans (ESPP)?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/119620/5656) got copied to https://qr.ae/TDNjXW by https://www.quora.com/profile/Jordan-Gambrell-2 in less than one minute. I've just reported this Jordan-Gambrell-2 user to Quora. If Quora doesn't take action within 1 week,  I will  [file a complaint to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/178179) via https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact.
- 2020-01-29: I've looked at Quora's content more systematically over the past few days and it is clear that thousands of questions have been copied, and very likely one or two order(s) of magnitude more (I'm guessing >10k questions). Quora still hasn't replied to me.  As a result, I have [filed a complaint to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/178179) via https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact.
- 2020-03-08: I haven't had any reply from Quora or Stack Exchange. [According to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343405/178179) from a Stack Exchange employee:

  > [Stack Exchange] don't send any follow-up because we do nothing with about 99.9% of those reports.
- 2020-07-07: Further examples by Dex Jackson are documented at the Chinese.SE meta: [Someone seems to be copy/pasting question titles to Quora without attribution](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1765/8099).  It is possible to watch the plagiarism taking place live on [Dex Jackson's Quora activity page](https://www.quora.com/profile/Dex-Jackson/activity). We can see on [Steve Tang's Quora activity page](https://www.quora.com/profile/Steve-Tang-6/activity) that Steve is also actively plagiarizing questions from Stack Exchange.
- 2020-07-09: Further examples by Dex Jackson are documented at the Math.SE meta: [Livestream plagiarism of question titles from Math.SE onto Quora](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32067/livestream-plagiarism-of-question-titles-from-math-se-onto-quora/) where there is a response from Quora; they (failing to see the irony) write:

  > Thank you for your report. It appears from your claim that you do not own the copyright of the and/or are not authorized to act on behalf of the owner.
  >
  > We ask that you provide more specific evidence that you own the copyright to the content in question, such as a copyright registration or other information supporting your claim.

  Meanwhile, [livestream plagiarism](https://www.quora.com/profile/Dex-Jackson/activity) continues.

So for now I'm simply double posting my questions on both Stack Exchange and Quora, which on the upside of makes it a bit easier to [retrieve the content of questions automatically removed on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209694/178179).

Comment: Also, if you own a *significant* copyright interest in a given post, you can file a DMCA takedown notice.

Comment: Do flag those Quora posts. I regularly investigate plagiarism *in the opposite direction* but come across content copied to Quora from here, and I regularly find the flagged posts deleted when revisiting later.

Comment: The unlisted questions are posted using the “limited” setting, see https://www.quora.com/How-is-it-that-Quora-users-ask-questions-and-get-answers-that-are-not-listed-on-their-profile-page-Some-users-have-not-been-active-for-months-yet-questions-are-generated-from-their-accounts/answer/Beth-Carrera?ch=10&share=622d1edb&srid=6oes These accounts are Quora Partner accounts hoping to make money from posting as many questions as possible.

Comment: And finally, you want to look at the *edits* tab on these users profiles; their questions may not be directly listed but all their posting activity is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I wasn't aware of the Quora partners and the limited setting (they didn't exist when I was using Quora actively). Time to report Quora users/partners!

Comment: "how can we make this systematic content license infringement stop?" Probably only if financial penalties can be tied to repeated such actions.

Comment: Hopefully they will copy this question.

Comment: If anyone is wondering the reason SE should never offer a paid option Quora Partner is an example of reason that should ever happen.

Comment: It *is* true that they don't take plagiarism (by the users) seriously at Quora, but why would they do it when they realise they would get caught in short order? They can't be *that* desperate for the VC exit (IPO?)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen At that point it is unclear if the copyright infringement is organized directly by Quora, independently by some Quora employees, a group of non-Quora employees trying to milk the Quora Partners program or just some hobbyists. We'll judge how IPO desperate Quora is based on their response, but definitely the brand of Quora as a high-quality question-answering website has sunk deeply over the past few years so they may be just aiming for quantity at that point and turning a blind eye on plagiarism.

Comment: The Quora CEO said few days ago that they need to "reduce our burn rate to a sustainable level" https://techcrunch.com/2020/01/23/layoffs-hit-qa-startup-quora/ so yes, they might be relatively desperate for cash.

Comment: @Nemo thanks, interesting, they better keep their lawyers though if they intend to keep trying to perform large scale copyright infringement.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I just clicked through the examples you gave at the beginning of your question and I don't see how any of the actual content has been duplicated, just the titles of the questions. Has something changed (the content was removed) or was it always the case that just the titles were copied over, without the body of the questions or the answers?

Comment: @dwizum Only titles were copied, because questions on Quora cannot have content, only titles. In many cases the questions are self-contained in the titles.

Comment: Thanks. I've never been to Quora before so I was a little confused.

Comment: Related (MSO): *[Curious case of copied code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393326/curious-case-of-copied-code/393327#comment751844_393327)*