# Send a follow-up email when a user reports that some Stack Exchange content is plagiarised by another website

Tags: feature-request, support, attribution, copycat-sites, screen-scraping

I [reported a website (Quora) copying a significant amount of Stack Exchange content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342516/178179) via https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact and got the following response from the Stack Overflow support team via email:

> Due to the nature of this request and the amount of time it takes to process them, it is unlikely that you will receive any further follow-up emails regarding this issue.

I very much appreciate the support of Stack Exchange in this matter but it would be nice if instead the reporter receives some follow-up emails to be able to track what is happening, at the very least when the case is closed.

---

Full email:

> ---------- Forwarded message ---------
>  From: Stack Overflow Community
>  Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2020 at 07:15
>  Subject: Re: Meta
>   Stack Exchange - Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without
>   attribution - [Ticket ID]
>  To: Franck Dernoncourt
>
> Hi Franck Dernoncourt,
>
> Thank you for reporting this content. I've passed the information
>   along to the person at our company who handles such issues. It's the
>   diligence of users like you that helps us stay valuable!
>   Please note, bringing these sites into compliance (or getting them to
>   no longer serve our content) is often a long and arduous process. You
>   may not see immediate results. However, rest assured that we're
>   working on it.
>  Due to the nature of this request and the
>   amount of time it takes to process them, it is unlikely that you will
>   receive any further follow-up emails regarding this issue.
>  
>   Regards,
>  Stack Overflow Team

Comment: I don't understand what you ask. SE states: We will not do any follow-up. And now you still insist they do? Is *No* not an acceptable answer for you?

Comment: @rene I am simply suggesting that a follow-up would be more considerate to the reporters, hence this feature request. It Stack Exchange insists on not doing any, then so be it.

Comment: I don't think adding more overhead to *a long and arduous process* is beneficial to the goal. There is nothing actionable for you once you know the case is closed.

Comment: @rene on the contrary, if the reporter is being notified that the case is closed in that no action was taken, then the reporter could take legal action themselves.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt if it's your content that is being used without respecting your license or without having the right to (re-)publish it I would always take action yourself regardless as you are the owner of the content (and have the copyright) and you are the one who actually can bring a legal case (if you want to pursue that).

Answer (score 32):

To be perfectly honest: we don't send any follow-up because we do nothing with about 99.9% of those reports. After we did analysis on scraper reports a couple years ago, we found that the vast majority of content scrapers go offline or the problem is otherwise resolved within a couple of months before we ever get around to doing anything about them. Tracking and dealing with these reports turned out to be mostly a waste of our time.

We continue accepting these reports because they do occasionally bear fruit and reveal a proxy that needs to be blocked or some other serious issue, and also because it makes users feel good that they are doing something positive for their community even if the desired action isn't likely to occur due to us doing something. But in most cases, we send that auto-reply and just close the ticket. No one else ever looks at it. There isn't follow-up to be had.

If you're very concerned about content being copied, we recommend looking into some of the options at the bottom of the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/141525).

Comment: Is there even something you (SE) can do as the content is not yours to begin with?

Comment: @PeeHaa Not really. Long ago we used to send messages to try and get them to comply with the license (assuming we could even *find* contact info for them), and would also report them to Google to make sure their content didn't appear above ours. The former rarely resulted in anything happening, and the latter is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks for the honesty.  I agree with the passive approach, but suggest that Quora is not "just" a scraper.  It's a large enough concern that I'd like to see our powers that be actively trying to shut that down, if nothing else just to show that our IP contributions are valued, and would appreciate M.SE updates on this particular matter.

Comment: In other words, I've been completely wasting my time, and you've wilfully and deliberately let me do it, and have _specifically_ not provided any feedback on the process because you didn't want me to find out. Nice. Thanks.

Comment: "at the *bottom* of the FAQ"? I'd rather that more important to-knows be put at the *top*.

Comment: @iBugsaysReinstateMonica Seems like the FAQ should be updated not to bother.