# Data stack exchange: query from all sites

Tags: support, data-explorer

While creating a query on Stack Exchange Explorer, how do you write a query to include all Stack Exchange sites?

```
select P.ID as [Post Link],
        p.Score,
        P.Title,
        P.OwnerDisplayName,
        P.ViewCount,
        pt.Name

from 
Posts as P
inner join
PostTypes as Pt
on P.posttypeid = pt.Id

where p.Score > ##score## AND (Something like include all site)
order by P.Score desc
```

Comment: a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148268/197141) exists for this

Comment: Why did you downvote?

Comment: sorry, I downvoted because a quick search turned up the answer from similar questions

Answer (score 2):

You cannot select all the Stack Exchange sites; the query is executed for the Stack Exchange site you select at the beginning.